# keys in object are undefined but object is not (react-redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have a strange issue with the data I'm fetching from an API. In my reducer I've set the initial state to an empty object and in my component's render method I'm accessing this fetched data using `this.props.data.value.one`.

The actual fetched data from the API look like this:

```
{data:
  {value: {one: '1'}}
}
```

However when I try to `console.log(this.props.data)` it will log `{value: {one: '1'}}` after logging `undefined` a couple of times but will log `this.props.data.value.one` as `undefined`.

I'm doing similar stuff in my other reducers which are getting data from other API's and they work fine.

**App.js Component:**

```
@connect(store => store)
...
componentWillMount = () => {//API Call here}
render = () => {
 return (
    <div><p>{this.props.data.value.one}</p><div>
 )
}
```

**reducer.js:**

```
...
export default function reducer(state={data: {}}, action) {
  ...
  case 'FETCHED_DATA':
    return {...state, data: action.data}
```

**action.js:**

```
...
fetchData = user => dispatch => {
  //request.get...
     .then(res => dispatch({type: 'FETCHED_DATA', data: res.body.data})
}
```

Comment: show some code please

Comment: what is the name of the `reducer`? it seems that the `data` object is nested inside it, `this.props.reducerName.data...`

Comment: did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you set you initial state to be an empty object, and the data you get is though an API call which is async, so when the component renders first time `this.props.data` is undefined.

What you need to do is check if the data is available before using it

Add a conditional check like

```
this.props.data && this.props.data.value.one
```

Comment: I'm doing the same thing in other components as well and I never had to put any such condition.

Comment: @m-ketan, what could be the case in other components is that they are rendered after the data has been fetched and hence this check is not needed and as you mention that in your App.js you have an API call in componentWillMount which can take some time to get you the result and your component can get rendered before that

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined initial state as data: {}, and not as data : {value : ''}, and thus when you fetched data from the api data object is not initialized as data.value to access it. Setting it to the latter should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues i see here:

1. As mentioned in other answers and comments, you should always
   conditionally access objects that are fetched asynchronously.

   ```
   this.props.myObj && this.props.myObj.myValue
   ```

   By the way, don't fetch inside `componentWillMount`, instead do it
   in `componentDidMount`.   You can read about the reasons for this in
   the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount).

   > Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
   >   For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.
2. By the look of the shape of your reducer (`state`) it seems that the
   `data` object is nested inside the reducer:

   ```
   state={data: {}}
   ```

   So you can't access it directly from props (unless you are changing
   the shape in `mapStateToProps`).

   So i would expect to see this:

   ```
   this.props.reducerName.data.value.one
   ```

   instead of this:

   ```
   this.props.data.value.one
   ```